# executing code without generating a new request

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

is the following scenario possible?

Let's say I have an Iterator[String] received from a controller and I want to partially iterate over it.

I'd like to do this without the need to generate an extra Request because the iterator is already in place. (by hitting a next button) Is this actually possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If by "in place" you mean the iterator is somehow returned from controller (JSON or other) and it's accessible in the view, there seem to be no problem to do partial iterate over it.

Comment: can you give an example for that?